# Array of threads in C++ Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, stdthread

I am trying to create an array with threads. My code looks like this:

```
boost::thread threads[10];

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         client c(io_services[i], "www.boost.org", "/");

         threads[i] ( boost::bind(workerFunc, i) );

  }
```

And I am getting compilation error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::thread) (boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> > >)’
       threads[i] ( boost::bind(workerFunc, i) );
```

I can not figure out what I need change in my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you including the boost header? [check this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/index.html) for more info

Comment: @JamesKirsch yes I am

Comment: thread constructor uses bind internally. try threads[i](&some_function);

Comment: @aayush93 still the same error. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
boost::thread threads[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    client c(io_services[i], "www.boost.org", "/");

    threads[i] = boost::thread( boost::bind(workerFunc, i) );
}
```